# BitmapImage returns 0 for PixelWidth and PixelHeight

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, bitmapimage

I'm trying to do a super simple thing : get the size of an image.

So I create my `BitmapImage` but I'm getting 0 when I try to access the `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight`.

How can I accomplish that please?

EDIT: (added sample code)

I'm just doing:

```
var baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///");
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(baseUri, "Assets/Logo.png"));

MyImage.Source = bitmapImage;

Debug.WriteLine("Width: " + bitmapImage.PixelWidth + " Height: " + bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
```

In the console, I get:

```
Width: 0 Height: 0
```

Comment: Most likely, the image was not loaded correctly. Set a breakpoint in the debugger and examine the contents of `image`. Alternative, try and display the contents of `image` somewhere on a window. Can you see anything? Is there even an image there?

Comment: @CodyGray. Yes the image is perfectly displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to use the image properties after setting the source for your [`BitmapImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br243235.aspx), you normally have to write an event handler that will execute on [`ImageOpened`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.imageopened.aspx).

Also remember that `ImageOpened` only fires if the image is downloaded and decoded (i.e. using [`Image.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source)).

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(uri);
bitmapImage.ImageOpened += (sender, e) => 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Width: {0}, Height: {1}",
        bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
};
image.Source = bitmapImage;
```

Comment: Is there a way to force the image to be downloaded (without setting image.source)?

Answer (score -2):

You can try to initialyze it in a different way. Try this:

```
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

// BitmapImage.UriSource must be in a BeginInit/EndInit block
myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
myBitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\pics\Water_Lilies.jpg");
myBitmapImage.EndInit();
int w = myBitmapImage.PixelWidth;
```

Comment: I'm making a Windows 8 store App and BeginInit() and EndInit() can't be used. Any ideas why?

Comment: What do you mean they "can't be used"?  What error are you getting?